# CSS style not inherited from class

Tags: css, html

I have two kinds of `<ul>` elements, one with `class="subcat"`, another without any identifier. I have the following `CSS` code:

```
ul, li {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.subcat {
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Isn't this supposed to make the `ul`s bolder in general, and any `ul` with the class `subcat` a bit less bold? `font-weight: 400;` is overriding `font-weight: 700;` for the `ul.subcat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 .subcat li {
   font-weight: 400;
 }
```

change `.subcat` to `.subcat li`

```css
ul, li {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.subcat li {
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test
        <ul class="subcat">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```